# ember.js ( 2.5) ember routing issue with belongsTo relationship

Tags: ember.js

In my ember app, I am displaying a list of books

```
    BOOKS
    Book                                Author             
    Gorgeous Metal Fish Cookbook        Jefferey Gibson
```

I am trying to display author's information ( in a modal window) upon click on the author's name
in my books template, I have an action 'showAuthor' , defined in the the books route, but I get undefined data...

```
<span {{action 'showAuthor' book}}>{{book.author.name}}</span>


    **TEMPLATES**
    <!-- app/templates/books.hbs -->
     <h1>Books</h1>
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
       <thead>
         . . .
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         {{#each model as |book|}}
           <tr>
             <td>
               . . .
            </td>
             <td>
               <span {{action 'showAuthor' book}}>{{book.author.name}}</span>
             </td>
           </tr>
         {{/each}}
       </tbody>
     </table>


    ============
    **MODELS**
    // app/models/book.js
    export default Model.extend({
        . . .
          author:       belongsTo('author', {inverse: 'books', async: true}),
        . . .
    });

    // app/models/author.js
    export default Model.extend({
        . . .
      books: hasMany('book', {inverse: 'author', async: true}),
        . . .
    });

    =========
    **ROUTES**
    app/routes/books.js    
    import Ember from 'ember';
    export default Ember.Route.extend({
      model() {
        return this.store.findAll('book');
      },
      actions: { 
        .. .
       showBookAuthor(book){
          alert('SHOW BOOK AUTHOR : ' + book.author.name);
        }, 
       . . .
      }
    });


    app/routes/authors.js    
    import Ember from 'ember';
    export default Ember.Route.extend({
      model() {
        return this.store.findAll('author');
      },
      actions: { 
        .. .
      }
    });
```

UPDATE 1
The action in mybooks template is correctly coded :

{{book.author.name}}

and the action , in the books route is correctly written :

```
   showBookAuthor(book){
      alert('SHOW BOOK AUTHOR : ' + book.author.nale);
   },
```

UPDATE 2

as stated in the guide" , While working with relationships it is important to remember that they return promises...

I updated my action :

```
    showBookAuthor(book){
  book.get('author').then((author) => {
    // now we can work with the author
    console.log('SHOW BOOK AUTHOR : ' + author.name);
  });
},
```

the console does not display the author;name but

```
SHOW BOOK AUTHOR : [object Object]
```

what's wrong with my coding ?  thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

In the template you are passing `book.author` to `showBookAuthor` action but in the `showBookAuthor` defined in the route you are expecting a book.
You should change the action to:

```
showBookAuthor(author){
    alert('SHOW BOOK AUTHOR : ' + author.name);
}
```

Comment: thanks , however I pasted a wrong test...   I updated my issue , with the correctly written code ... passing 'book'  and trying to display book.author.name in the alert ....  in both cases ( passing abook , or passing a book.author ) I don't get the alert ...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED :**

I should write my action as following :

```
  showBookAuthor(book){
  book.get('author').then((author) => {
    // now we can work with the author
    console.log('SHOW BOOK AUTHOR : ' + author.get('name'));
  });
},
```